# Can I change account type on elance from individual to company

Tags: user-accounts

After upgrading to Small company membership, will I be able to add company description in “About the Company” section in place of Resume/C.V which is there in my current account as it is Individual membership plan?

My purpose for upgrading is to describe my company, add company logo, company services, add team members and have more connects.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](http://help.elance.com/hc/en-us/articles/203735543-What-are-the-Freelancer-Membership-plans-How-do-I-upgrade-my-Membership-). Upgrading is fairly simple, and can be done with a few clicks.